# What are the connotations of a woman calling a man a “bananinha da madrinha”?

Tags: significado, origem-histórica

What does it mean when a woman calls a man, *bananinha da madrinha*?

What does it say about the kind of relationship between those two people?

Here are some images of this expression in context.

First page:

[image]

Second page:

[image]

Comment: Could it be *bananinha da madrinha*?

Comment: Yes it is bananinha da madrinha

Comment: *Madrinha* is *godmother*. *Bananinha* is diminutive of *banana*: the *inha* can mean small or can be used to make it sound affectionate. So if a woman says to a male *tu és a bananinha da madrinha* is like saying *I'm your godmother, and you're my bananinha*. *Banana* could have a sexual conotation here, owing to its shape. Something you could say to your boyfriend, but might want to avoid otherwise.

Comment: Note that I had never heard it before. I'm from Portugal, and maybe it will mean something different in Brazil. Let's see what the other people say.

Comment: Because it is difficult to read those words.

Comment: Also you should delete your duplicate question. You may have to finish your registration for that. Check the email StackExchange sent you (at the email address you provided) and follow the instrutions.

Comment: I have added 2 images as answer below ..can you please see and tell me that in which context that woman is talking to that boy. These pictures shows which kind of relationship between them

Comment: @Floral From what I could read, it looks like to be something close to "bacaninha de madrinha", "bananinha de madeira", or something else. It's difficult to identify the first word.

Comment: Hi Bruno .can you please tell me the meaning of this now ?

Comment: @Floral Well, it doesn't make much sense, but *"bacaninha"* is the diminutive (or affectionate form) for *"bacana"*, that means *"nice"* or *"cool"* (person, in this case). So *"bacaninha de madrinha"* would be something like *"godmother's nice person"*. *"Bananinha de madeira"* is *"wooden little banana"*. But keep in mind that I'm not sure if that's really what is written.

Comment: I **definitely** read «madeira» and not «madrinha».

Comment: @ANeves Me too, I just repeated what was said before and added "bacaninha". But really it's "b???nha de madeira".

Comment: The second word is definetly not *madrinha*. It's likely *madeira*. The first is hard to tell too. *Bananinha da Madeira* is *little banana/dear banana from Madeira (island)*, but it looks like *de*, not *da*; and a lower case *m*, not *M*. I think this is beyond us.

Comment: Thank god that everything people say or write is not codified in some dictionary. Maybe the T-shirt she is sending has a picture of Madeira with a banana on it. Could be: http://www.visitmadeira.pt/pt-pt/o-que-fazer/eventos/pesquisa/banana A banana é super importante na/para Madeira, e existem várias variedades.....

Comment: That sounds like an **"inside joke"**.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

To me, it says nothing about your relationship; it just seems to be a reference to something in the past, that you are expected to remember.

## The words are «bananinha de madeira»

- The first word is clearly «banana».
- The rest is clearly «de madeira»;

  - it's not «da» - notice how the `a` is written in the other words, and the `e` in «madeira»;
  - it's **not** «madrinha»: it's missing the `h`; and what would be an `r` is written like the `e` in «de»; and the `n` from «nha» is not written like the `n` from «banana».

So what could «bananinha de madeira» mean?

## She's the banana

«Bananinha de madeira» refers to the sender (A.F.) and not the receiver (you). It is written next to the sender's name, like a title or a nickname would.
It should not refer to you.

It seems like she is referring to something you ought to recognize.

It could be meant as a nickname for AF.
Alternatively, she could be referring to a place, story, or event that you could remember in order to associate with who was there, and that way remember her more easily.

## Banana

[Banana](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/banana) could mean:

- Literally, a banana;
- In slang, the penis;
- Figuratively, an idiot (um banana) - a stunted individual, without energy or initiative, or even a coward who won't take action.

## Bananinha

«Banana» was used in the diminutive.
This is probably a form of endearment. (The Portuguese shopkeepers [particularly like this literary device (comical sketch)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7c34rg7RJqA).)

## Madeira

If it was «banana d**a** **M**adeira», it would be about the bananas from Madeira. The word «Madeira» should have been capitalized, but the low caps could be blamed on informal writing.
In Portugal, bananas from Madeira are very famous and appreciated, like in Spain the bananas from the Canary Islands.

But the words written are «banana **de** madeira». A wooden banana.
If it was not an accidental typo, I don't really know what it could mean.

## Conclusion

what is all this about?
What does it mean?
What could its nuances and secondary meanings be?
**And what does it say about the relationship?**

I don't know.
It's not clear what it could mean. It seems to be a reference to something that happened, or was told, in the past.

Then instead of thinking too much about it, my suggestion is to take things lightly, make a joke back about [bananas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCIDWVWWI3o), and try to read from the answer to that.
Communication is imprecise, and sometimes there's the need to improvise. :)

Comment: kkkk Escreveu um tratado pra chegar em lugar nenhum... Mas gostei rs

Comment: @EnricoBrasil queria corrigir a leitura e esclarecer umas coisas, mas isso não cabia num comentário; então acabei por adicionar uma resposta, que foi crescendo... no fundo acho que afinal tinha era saudades deste lugar, por causa das férias. ;)

Answer (score 3):

*baianinha de madeira* is the meaning, because when you go to Bahia or Minas Gerais (Brazil) you can see some of these:
[image: Namoradeira]

**Namoradeira** means something like *flirt*, a name for the sculpture in the image above.

**Baianinha de madeira** is the other name you can give to it, relates a woman who is waiting a love for her, more romantic.

*baianinha* has a diminutive suffix *inha* of the word *baiana* (someone who is born in the state of Bahia).

*de madeira* is a quality of that *baiana*, means made of wood.

Maybe the correct relationship about that postcard is she saying:

> I'm waiting for you.

Or

> Your Brazilian friend from Bahia.

Considering a postcard, maybe they're so far from each other.
Also, by referring a person in diminutive suffix, she is very kind, lovable with him.

More info in [English](https://www.etsy.com/listing/237438091/handmade-namoradeiras-afro-brazilian):

> Girls in small Brazilian towns had a very strict upbringing, and were
>   not allowed on the streets to meet men. So the girls had to find
>   inventive ways of meeting prospective husbands – and standing on the
>   window, waiting for prince charming to start a chat was one of these
>   methods.